# Sum of first fraction of binomials

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients

Let $$B(n,p)=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\dots+\binom{n}{\lfloor pn\rfloor}.$$

It is clear that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{B(n,1/2)}{2^n}=\frac12.$$ 
Is it true that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{B(n,p)}{2^n}=0$$ 
for any $0\leq p<1/2$?

Comment: Well, for one thing, $A(n)=2^n$.

Comment: @Arthur Fair enough :P

Comment: Try using central limit theorem, or Chernoff bound.